# Set of rationals isomorphic to $\omega \cdot \omega$

Tags: set-theory

I have the following problem, but I don't know how to solve it:

**Problem.** Describe a set of rationals isomorphic to $\omega \cdot \omega$

Comment: MathJax hint:  to get the multiplication dot, use \cdot so \omega \cdot \omega will give $\omega \cdot \omega$

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you sketch $\omega \cdot \omega$ in some way?  Can you find a set of rationals isomorphic to $\omega$?  Can you extend the technique used?

Comment: I am looking for an example of a set of rationals such that it is an isomorphism to $\omega \cdot \omega$

Comment: I understand that.  I was asking if you knew how to do two simpler things, which could lead you to the solution.  One way to sketch $\omega$ is to draw a long vertical segment, put a shorter one next to it, a shorter one next to that, and so on giving the feel that they run off to infinity in perspective.  Have you seen a sketch like that?  Does that give you an idea for a set isomorphic to $\omega$?  What would $\omega \cdot \omega$ look like?

Answer (score 0):

For $n\in \Bbb Z^+$ let $S_n\subset \Bbb Q\cap [n,n+1)$ be order-isomorphic to $\omega$ with $\min S_n=n$ and $\sup S_n=n+1.$ Now let $S=\cup_{n\in \Bbb Z^+}S_n.$

More generally, let $<'$ be a linear order on a non-empty countable set $B$. A jump in $B$ is an ordered pair $<x,y>$ of members of B with $x<'y,$ such that $no$ $z\in B$ satisfies $x<'z<'y.$ Augment $B$ to a larger ordered set $C$ by (i) inserting a copy of $\Bbb Q$ between $x$ and $y$ whenever $<x,y>$ is a jump in $B$, and (ii) adding a copy of $\Bbb Q$ below $\min_{<'}B$ if this min exists, and (iii) adding a copy of $\Bbb Q$ above $\max_{<'}B$ if this max exists. Then $C$ satisfies the premise of this (elementary) theorem of Georg Cantor:

A countably infinite linear order with no jumps, no min, and no max, is order-isomorphic to $\Bbb Q.$

So let $f:C\to \Bbb Q$ be an order-isomorphism. Then $f|_B$ is an order-isomorphism from $B$ to a subset of $\Bbb Q.$ Therefore any countable linear order (e.g. any countable ordinal) is order-isomorphic to a subset of $\Bbb Q.$

We can also use transfinite induction (without that Cantor theorem) to show that every countable ordinal embeds into $\Bbb Q.$